# Constants for anti-derivatives

Tags: calculus, integration, physics

Hey StackExchange I'm diving into integral calculus for the first time and I have a few questions about this problem.

**A steel ball bearing at rest is accelerated in a magnetic field in a line with acceleration a(t) = 120t meters per second.**

**(a) Find the velocity and position at time t.**

**(b) Find its position in meters and velocity in meters per second after 0.5 second.**

So I get the velocity by finding the anti-derivative of acceleration and I find position by getting the anti-derivative of velocity.

$$v(t) = 60t^2 + c$$

$$p(t) = ct + 20t^3 + c_{1}$$

I'm not sure how I would go about answering the questions though. What do I use for a constant when plugging in values? Thanks!

Comment: You have a typo in your position function $p(t)$, in that generally the two "constants of integration" will be distinct.  The problem states the steel ball to be "at rest", so $v(0)=0$ seems justified.  The similar argument for position "zero" at time zero is less justified, but this is probably what was intended.  Check with instructor.

Comment: You can specify that $v(0)=v_0$ and $p(0)=p_0$ and express the constants $c_1, c_2$ generally using $v_0$ and $p_0$.

Answer (score 1):

$\textbf{"at rest"}$ i.e. $v(t=0)=0$ is the important piece of information.

Also the integrating to get the position is a tad wrong with the constants. 
$$
p(t) = 20t^3 + ct + \textbf{c}_1
$$

and since the postion is relative measure we can treat the starting point as zero displacement and therefore $p(t=0)=0$ also.

Answer (score 1):

First things first: when you integrate twice like you did, you will have two (generally different) constants of integration.  Thus, your equations should look like

$$v(t) = 60t^2 + c_1$$
$$p(t) = 20t^3 + c_1t + c_2.$$

(An easy way to see why we should have two different constants of integration is the consider units.  The values $ct$ and $c$ will have different units, so we can't add them together!)

Since the ball bearing begins at rest, $v(0) = 0$.  If we agree that the ball bearing begins at position $0$ (or if we just decide that $p$ should represent the displacement of the ball bearing rather than it's absolute position), then we also have $p(0) = 0$.  With these two equations, you can form a system of equations to solve for $c_1$ and $c_2$.

Comment: This would render $c_{1} = -60t^2$ and $c_{2} = 40t^3$ correct?

Comment: Not quite: we aren't saying that $v(t) = 0$ always, just that $v(0) = 0$.  Also, we know that $v(0) = 60\times (0)^2 + c_1$.  Can you figure out what $c_1$ is based on this?  And then do the same thing for $c_2$?

Comment: So that would be $c_1 = 0$ and $c_2 = -20t^3$, correct?

Comment: No, you have to go through the same process with $p$ to get $c_2$.  What is $p(0)$ (both based on plugging $0$ in for $t$, and how we defined our coordinate system)?

Comment: Sorry this is taking so long, I'm at the last calculus binge at the end of my semester and I'm pretty burned out, here are my steps: $v(0) = 0 = 60(0)^2 + c_1$ so $c_1 = 0$, $p(0) = 0 = 0 + 20(0)^3 + c_2$ so $c_2 = 0$, I doubt this is right so I must be misinterpreting you.

Comment: Nope, you got it right!  $c_1 = 0, c_2 = 0$ is the only combination of $c_1$ and $c_2$ that gives you $v(0) = 0$ and $p(0) = 0$.